# Handle facebook confirmation popup from rest service

Tags: java, rest, facebook-graph-api

I have following requirement,Through rest service,I need to fetch feed from facebook and store in db.I have to do this for every one hour.

I have created App in Graph_Api,when i want to communicate with graph api for the first time, below mentioned pop-up is coming. As i told you, i am doing from backend so no manual interaction to click on **Continue as DevSample**. Is there any way to get out of this through rest? please suggest

Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Feed of _what_ - a specific user profile, or a page? If page, is the page public and the posts you are interested in are all visible to everyone? In that case, your app access token will do.

Comment: i need to retrieve feed from user managed groups, i have admin access for that group. while fetching feeds from that group i am getting this popup. if i click on <continue as devsample>, able to get all feed information. Through app access token, we can't retrieve group information- User access token will do that. my doubt is, how can i handle this popup while calling graph api through rest

Comment: Then you should extend your user access token, so that it is valid for up to 60 days, and store it somewhere. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension After that, you will have to go through the whole process again - get a new short-lived user access token (that requires the dialog & user interaction, can’t be fully automated), and extend it.